# Fragments / light splotches in gpu render but not cpu render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

So I’m trying to render this glass full of liquid, it renders fine on CPU render but on GPU render I get wired fragments/splotches in the shadows. I already tried reloading the kernels and all that but, nothing has worked

Cpu Amd ryzen 7 2700x
Gpu rx 5700
blender: 2.82a / 2.81 (tried both)

GPU render did work on a different computer which was some old 700 GPU 
[image: render results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things;

1: It actually looks like the GPU is rendering more realistically. I think the reduction in quality would be /not/ having those artifacts (though this is debatable)

2: If you're rendering with Cycles, check to see if you have "Supported" or "Experimental" selected for the feature set. This setting will certainly cause rendering differences;

[image]

Comment: ok that does make sense, I did have a model error that made the problem much worse., but how does the explain when I used a Nivida GPU on a different computer, I got the same result as the CPU? or does it matter if that GPU was many times weaker than my main one? (rx5700). Regardless I think I may just want to try to remodel this and see if that fixes my issue. Also experimental did not change anything. Thanks